# Quotes errors in MySql queries after update php to 5.4

Tags: php, xampp, quotes

I have an application made ​​in php and my database is mysql.
For years the application worked correctly, but a few days ago I updated my version of XAMPP, and it was updated my version of PHP, now I have the 5.4.
The problem now is to query database. The application is for a hospital, and, for example, I have many patients with last names containing single quotes. For example: Claudio O'Connor.
When I perform an update on this table, with some patient containing double quotes in its name, obviously the application fails.
For example:

```
UPDATE patients SET lastname = 'O'Connor' WHERE idPatient = 92565
```

I think this problem has to do with the deprecation of the magic quotes.
The problem is that the application is immense, and I can not fix this problem by looking at all the queries one by one.
Is there any way to fix this problem in general?
Thank you very much.

Comment: you use `mysql_real_escape_string` ??

Comment: no, I'm not using that function.
I know I can fix it that way, but that would have to use it in many pages.
I have the hope to solve by some settings. perhaps in an .ini file or something..

Comment: Do you use PDO or mysql_query?

Comment: You need to review the change log when you upgrade software. Its not there just for show. [Migrating from PHP 5.3.x to PHP 5.4.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php) Better check it now to see what else might be waiting to bite you

Comment: I'm using mysql_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.4, the automatic magic quotes feature was removed from PHP. If you're running a version older than 5.4, you can set `magic_quotes_gpc = On` in the php.ini (or by using the following):

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', '1');
```

If you're using 5.4+, you'll need to manually apply `mysql_real_escape_string` to all data. Note that for SQL injection prevention, you should not rely on magic quotes and instead use manual code to escape the string.

Answer (score 0):

Activating manually the `magic_quotes_gpc` or or sanitizing the inputs with `mysql_real_string_escape` are quick fixes that will work fine but you should really consider to use PDO prepared statements that don't have any SQL Injection issues.

Here is an example of what it looks like

```
<?php
$insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO fruit(name, colour) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert->execute(array('apple', 'green'));
$insert->execute(array('pear', 'yellow'));

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Group values by the first column */
var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP));
?>
```